# Sphinx index rotation timestamp

Tags: php, sphinx

Is there a way to get the timestamp when an index has been last rotated by sphinx? Preferably with PHP.

So, for example I issue an indexer --all --rotate command via cron at night. I would like to get the timestamp from that operation in case the index rotation was successful (i.e. sphinx was reloaded with new indexes). Apparently I would also like to get a list of available indexes from sphinx, but that is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `sql_query_post_index`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-post-index

to record it somewhere.

Looking in that table, would also give you the list of indexes :)

Comment: Thanks for good thinking :) We tend to get used to all sorts of APIs and forget about elegant solutions!